# Group only if Link already exists (MySQL)

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this raw table:
[image]

And what I want to have at the end is the following:

[image]

1. Show each day
2. Show kategorie
3. Show Count(ID) -> And if link is matching link and, day is matching day and kategorie is matching kategorie count one up.

I nearly have the solution. The only problem right now is that the query is not considering link differences. Because for example for day 1 and kategorie `Terkkingräder` I have 2 different links but the query is grouping them nevetherless.

This is my query right now

```
SELECT COUNT(ID) AS Anzahl, DAY(STR_TO_DATE(datum, '%Y-%m-%d')) AS Datum, kategorie, link FROM `4184_lead_tracking` WHERE datum >= '2017-12-01' AND datum <= '2017-12-31' GROUP BY DAY(datum), kategorie, link ORDER BY DAY(datum) ASC
```

I appreciate any kind of help. Kind regards!

Comment: My help will be in the form of a criticism, go read on normalizing your database. This is no good. You have duplicate (triple) entries for ids: `50, 59, 68`, `46,55,64`, `49,58,67`, `52,61,70` and `6,51`. At least category and link should have their own table. With a normalized database you would not be having this issue.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, you have three identical entries for day 1. The links are exactly the same, and this is why they are grouped as one element.